# Como instalar Certbot SSL en 2 puertos Nginx

Tags: javascript, nodejs, backend, nginx, certificado-ssl

he instalado Certbot SSL en mi frontend `www.miweb.cl:3000` y funcionó todo bien, pero al agregarle SSL a mi backend[nodejs] (`www.miweb.cl::4000`) perdí el "Candado" en mi frontend y solo lo tengo en mi backend, como puedo tener SSL en ambos puertos?.

Backend:

```
const credenciales = {
key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/miweb.cl/privkey.pem'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/miweb.cl/cert.pem'),
ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/miweb.cl/chain.pem')
};
```

Esto es lo que tengo en `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/miweb.cl`

```
server {
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }


listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/miweb.cl/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/miweb.cl/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
if ($host = www.miweb.cl) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


if ($host = miweb.cl) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

    server_name miweb.cl www.miweb.cl;
listen 80;
return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Si necesitan mas info no duden en preguntar. Gracias de antemano